# Table with uneven row heights

Tags: html, html-table, rows

I've got this problem with an HTML table. The left column should have 3 rows (I was just playing around in the image you see below), the right just 1. I want to place text in the upper left corner of the first row of the left column. I can place text, but it isn't in the upper left corner.

[image: https://s28.postimg.org/4ndolmubh/Naamloos.png]

This is my code:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;" rowspan="7"><img src="http://chorix.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Achtergrond.gif" alt="" width="570" height="570" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-378" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `vertical-align`. By default this is set to `middle` for table cells, but you can set it to `top`:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top"> ... </td>
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top;">a</td>
      <td style="width: 50%;" rowspan="7"><img src="http://chorix.be/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Achtergrond.gif" alt="" width="570" height="570" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-378" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 50%;">a</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: No problem. Be sure to mark the answer as "accepted" if you found that it was a sufficient solution to your question!